# Is Revivify Commonly Used?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

As I'm planning out my bard character, I've found myself at a small impasse: I'm stuck between whether I should take Shape Water, a versatile spell I can see myself using quite often, or Revivify, something that could save my party members from having to role play their dramatic death, since we only have a barbarian, wizard, and myself, a bard.

Which is more practically chosen? Worded differently to clarify, is it that often that Revivify is needed? Or is it something that can be ignored in lieu of another avenue?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based, this sort of poll question is better suited for a traditional discussion forum. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated forum list.

Comment: @Thomas Markov Rats, I was trying to avoid that. If I'm asking for the usage rate of Revivify in games, is that opinion-based?

Comment: That would still be opinion based because there’s no wrong answer. Two people can have wildly different answers here that are both factual. And those answers won’t help you unless you happen to play at a table that matches that experience.

Comment: That's valid, and actually somewhat answers my question, though not in the way I expected. Thank you!

Comment: 'How often is revivify chosen?' is opinion-based.  'As a bard in a three-person party with a barbarian and a wizard, will my bard need to take healing spells?' might be ok, and I can already think of a number of related questions.  'If my bard was the party healer, how beneficial would Revivify be'? might be ok.

Comment: I think there can be factual answers about how common something is statistically over a wider player population, even if those would be of no use at a specific table that widely deviates. It is possible to ask such questions if done right, but its often met with resistance, and downvotes by those that dislike them. You can read some of the thinking why these are considered not useful [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12252/75095)

Comment: Your most important questions to ask (yourself) are probably how would you feel if someone died and you didn't take revivify, how would it go down at the table, and how do you feel about keeping that last 3rd level slot unused all day every day because of those expectations.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin It would be very hard to run the required surveys for such answers to work.

Comment: @GMJoe but should we close questions because they are hard? Somehow wotc use statistical data to develop and rebalance things, and they can't survey everything even if they have larger reach than many.

Comment: An answer summarizing the opinions of 1000 people is still opinion based, and is only useful to the OP if they just happen to sit down at a table that matches the experience of whatever poll response they chose to model their expectations after.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov An answer summarizing the opinions (or in truth, usage) of 1000 people becomes a statistical study. Should the [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) of such research be low enough (usually <0.05 for serious research papers) and the procedure avoid biases (group pressure, ...), it goes outside one individual's perspective.

Comment: I am just curious as to how your situation has you deciding between taking a cantrip or a 3rd level spell. Like how does that happen in your build?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Fair question. It's because of Magical Secrets and Magic Initiate, and balancing what I want with what I can do. That caused Revivify from Magical Secrets to compete with Shape Water from Magic Initiate, since I wanted Find Familiar and Shape Water from one feat, but I could shift things around more comfortably if I dropped Revivify, which I had planned on taking due to the recommendation of rpg.bot. It's hard to explain and I'm tired, so I hope that was clear.